# Using Find on a List of custom objects with a complex predicate

Tags: c#, list

This may not be the right way to do this, but here goes...

I have a list of 'rules' that I'm defining in XML along the lines of..

```
<Config>
  <Rule key1="1" key2="Jack" value="Red" />
  <Rule key1="2" key2="John" value="Blue" />
  ...
</Config>
```

I'm trying to come up with a way that new 'rules' can be defined and used outside of re-compiling and testing program.

So the program deserializes the XML into a list of custom objects (List). No problem so far.

Now, I want to use a Find to do something like... (C#)

```
Rule found = rules.Find(x => (x.key1 == "2") && (x.key2 == "John"));
```

... returns the 2nd rule from above and hence the value I'm looking for of "Blue".

Is this even possible or am I way off base?

Comment: Just for the record, have you tried using [Configuration Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)?

Comment: I thought about it, but ultimately this file will be in the hands of a user (he said with fear and trepidation), so for my long term purposes, this needs to be a separate file. An app.config file would be on a server where the user would have no access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Rule found = rules.SingleOrDefault(r => r.key1 == "2" && r.key2 == "John");
```

Quoting MSDN:

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

Note that `found` will be `null` if no element was found that satisfies the given expression.

Also, it will throw an [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) if there is **more than one** element in your list that satisfies the condition.

I think this is expected since you are doing a search based on unique keys for each rule. If there are two rules that have the same keys, an exception should be raised.

---

If you are expecting **exactly one element** (and to throw an exception if there are more or none is found), you should use [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Rule found = rules.Single(r => r.key1 == "2" && r.key2 == "John");
```

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Comment: It worked! Many thanks! Or as we say in "Texas Spanglish", Much grass!